# How to user onClick event with php variables on a link?

Tags: javascript, php, html

What is the correct way to call the onClick event inside a link sending php variables?

I try to use the following code but is not working.

```
echo"<td><a href='/ADMIN/deletebooks.php?ID=".$row['ID']." onClick='return confirm('Do you really want to delete this book?')''>Delete</a></td>";
```

My javascript function is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmChk(){
{
 if(confirm("Do you  really want to delete this book?");
  return true;
 } 
  else{
   return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: You're not calling the `ConfirmChk()` function, you're calling `confirm()`. And you have quoting problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling your `ConfirmChk()` function. You were also missing a quote at the end of the `href`, and had an extra quote after the `onclick` (maybe that was just an editing mistake when you added the `onclick`). It should be:

```
echo"<td><a href='/ADMIN/deletebooks.php?ID=".$row['ID']."' onclick='return ConfirmChk()'>Delete</a></td>";
```

You can also simplify the function. You don't need `if/else`, since `confirm()` returns `true` or `false`.

```
function ConfirmChk() {
    return confirm("Do you really want to delete this book?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you forgot to close the href with a single quote.

```
echo"<td><a href='/ADMIN/deletebooks.php?ID=".$row['ID']."' onClick='return confirm('Do you really want to delete this book?')''>Delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: There are still quoting problems. You're using the same quotes as the delimiter around `onclick` and around the argument to `confirm`, and there's an extra quote after the confirm.